# Why did sometimes an embedded EJB Transaction break in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jpa, transactions, ejb

In my EJB (JEE6) I have a strange behavior wen I use nested transactions using JPA and MySQL.

I have the following code pattern:

```
|-> EJB Method1  @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
|   Transaction-1 started
|   INSERT INTO .... (ca. 30MB)
|   calling someEJB.method2();
|---> EJB Method2  @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
|    | Transaction-2 started
|    | INSERT INTO......
|    | JPA EntityManager.flush();
|<---+ Transaction-2 finished
|   INSERT INTO..... (ca. 30MB)
|   JPA EntityManager.flush();
|<- Transaction-1 finished
```

In most cases this works without problems. But when Transaction-2 inserts a lot of data (30MB) then sometimes (not every time) the hole transaction breaks with the following Exception from MySQL:

```
[#|2014-08-    02T15:06:08.116+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/office/office-ejb-1.1.1_jar/_org.imixs.workflow.jee.jpa|_ThreadID=132;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|
Local Exception     Stack:
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting     transaction
Error Code: 1205
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
```

When I remove the transaction type 'REQUIRES_NEW' from method 2 (default to 'REQUIRED') then the code seems to work without any problem.
It looks like transaction-1 locks the SQUENCE table and than is intercepted immediate by transaction-2 which runs in a dead-lock.

So my question is: 
Is is allowed to call a EJB method with TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW during a running Transaction, when transaction2 also operates on the same SQL Tables as transaction-1 ? Or is this a bad pattern which I should avoid?

Or is this something in MySQL what works wrong? I am using a XADatabase Pool and running my EJBs in GlassFish using EclipseLink.